# Self-illumination vs luminance

Tags: 3d, lighting, global-illumination

I'm using a graphics format reading library which has an enum called "MaterialLuminanceMode". There are three luminance modes for materials available:

- Self-illumination, which I interpret to mean "glow", as in a glowing light bulb,
- Color emission, which I interpret to be using the diffuse color mask for the lumination,
- Luminance, which I interpret to be the exact same as self-illumination.

Does anybody know what the difference between the first and third enum value is?

---

[The best resource I could find](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-70B5937B-23A0-42F1-966A-EC10A3A3F07B-htm.html) seems to suggest that self-illumination is a superset of luminance, but I'm still not certain what exactly separates the two! Note this is from 3ds, which i also an Autodesk product - although not the exact format I'm reading (which is DWG)

Comment: What is the library you are using?

Comment: OpenDesign, it's poorly documented, closed source and rather pricey